# How to generate Flex VO from database

Tags: database, apache-flex, actionscript, value-objects

We already have the database with real data inside. Now we want to build a Flex-Java on top of that. We know how to and did generate/reverse-engineering Java code from the Database using Hibernate tools. The question now is just how to generate the VO action script !
The idea is simple like the Hibernate generate POJO from DB.

Note: We tried data model-driven approach from Adobe but we don't like it.

Comment: I edited this question to remove your complaint about Adobe pricing; as this is not a place for such discussions.

Comment: How about the GraniteDS and AS3code generation they have ?

Comment: We'd like to have Plain Old Flex Object generated from POJO (Plain Old Java Object). Is that possible ?
- GAS3 from GraniteDS is poorly documented and is no longer in their dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using Java / Hibernate on the server side, then [ClearToolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/) from the guys at Farata would be a pretty good candidate to generate Flex code from what Hibernate already generated. Not to mention it's free.

Comment: I heard about it but failed to install on Indigo :(. It said "bundle com.adobe.flexbuilder.project 0.0.0" is not found

Comment: According to the [wiki](http://www.cleartoolkit.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=clearwiki:20.cleardatabuilder:01.setup:01.prerequisites) Indigo should be fine. Do you have FlashBuilder installed? It seems to be required (though it's not crystal clear).

Comment: failed to install on eclipse Indigo alone and on Flash Builder alone. Finally it went through when I installed it on Eclipse Indigo with FlashBuilder as plugin. I am trying it. Will let you know the result

Comment: RIAstar: it is an amazing tool, but the generated code is as complicated as the one generate by Adobe datamodel tool. We'd like to have Plain Old Flex Object generated from POJO (Plain Old Java Object). Is that possible ?

Comment: OK. I think ClearKit is acceptable solution. Although it is not very straightforward but, the solution is quite clean and easy to use. Just add @FXClass to POJO, the generated will be almost POFO. To beginners like me: you my want to open Their Website / Clear Toolkit Docs / General Docs to know how it works

Comment: @PhamHuyAnh I have written my own code generator (in Ruby) that does just that, but it's definitely not production quality :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
The question now is just how to generate the VO action script
```

1. Write the VOs by hand
2. Use a code generation tool.  I believe some stuff is built into [Adobe Flash Builder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4-668f02f4120d422cf08-8000.html).  Is that what you tried?
3. Use some other code generation tool.  I don't know of any out of the box.  I've used [Enteprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) to generate code from UML diagrams before, but not in ages.

Answer (score 0):

We use GraniteDS

http://www.graniteds.org/

Comment: Normally, I would -1 you for not specifying that there is a big difference between the GraniteDS toolkit and a very specific part of the toolkit, the GAS generator that will allow you to generate value objects from java POJOs. You can perfectly use only that specific part and not use the rest of GraniteDS. Try answering questions as specifically as possible.